# Session cookie is not getting deleted on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies, session-cookies

I am trying to set a session cookie on Internet Explorer. Per my understanding, a cookie created without an expiry date would be treated as session cookie. But when I do this on other browsers like chrome and firefox, it works pretty well. Cookie gets deleted as soon as browser tab is closed. However, it is not the same case in Internet Explores. Cookie still persists even after restart of the browser.
Below is the code,

document.cookie="test=12345;path=/";

Comment: That line of code shouldn't create such problem. Are you sure the cookie is created just like that and never tampered with? In IE 9 when you use Ctrl+Shift+Del option, you delete only persistent cookies. If you want to delete session one, you must hit F12 to open the Developer Tools, click Cache and Delete session cookie. Try making a separate HTML file and write that line of code. It is session-based even in IE.

Comment: @AlexStack  Deleting cookies through developer tools is out of scope of the question. Try executing this line of code in console of both IE and chrome. Restart the browser and print cookies.